# Category List in React

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

I changed my NavBarDesktop to add props in super like below.  My HomePage shows but if I click on About Us or any other page, I get a blank page.  I also added my HomePage Code below as well.  I am not sure why it does this.  If I take const MyView our the pages work but there is no categories in NavDropdown.

**NavMenuDesktop**

```
    class NavMenuDesktop extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
   
  }
  
    render(){

      const CatList = this.props.data;

      const MyView = CatList.map((CatList,i)=>{
        return <div key={i.toString()}>
         <NavDropdown.Item href="">{CatList.category_name}</NavDropdown.Item>
          </div>
        });
        return(
            <Fragment>
                    <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg" sticky="top">
  <Container>
  <Navbar.Brand href="/"><img src={Logo} className="nav-logo" /></Navbar.Brand>    
  <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" className="nav-toggler" ><i className="fa fa-bars"></i></Navbar.Toggle>
      <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
      <Nav className="me-auto">
      <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="/about">About Us</Nav.Link>
        <NavDropdown title="Shop" id="basic-nav-dropdown" renderMenuOnMount={true}>
      {MyView}
        </NavDropdown>
        <Nav.Link href="/contact">Contact</Nav.Link>
   
      <NavDropdown title="My Account" id="collasible-nav-dropdown" renderMenuOnMount={true}>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="/login"><i className="fa fa-sign-in-alt p-2 colorred"></i>Login</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2"><i className="fa fa-user-plus p-2 colorred"></i>Register</NavDropdown.Item>
  </NavDropdown>

            <ul className="inline justify-content-right">
            <li><Nav.Link href="/favorites"><i className="fa fa-heart fa-md text-secondary"></i>
      <sup><span className="badge text-white bgred fa-md">5</span></sup>
      </Nav.Link></li>
      <li><Nav.Link href="/cart"><i className="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-md text-secondary"></i>
      <sup><span className="badge text-white bgred fa-md">5</span></sup>
      </Nav.Link>
      </li>
      </ul>
        </Nav>
    
    </Navbar.Collapse>

    
 
  </Container>
</Navbar>

            </Fragment>
     
    




        )
    }
}

export default NavMenuDesktop;
```

**HomePage**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import AppURL from '../api/AppURL';
import AppRoute from '../route/AppRoute';
import FeaturedProducts from '../components/home/FeaturedProducts';
import Categories from '../components/home/Categories';
import Collection from '../components/home/Collection';
import NewArrival from '../components/home/NewArrival';
import HomeTop from '../components/home/HomeTop';
import NavMenuDesktop from '../components/common/NavMenuDesktop';
import FooterDesktop from '../components/common/FooterDesktop'
import axios from 'axios';


class HomePage extends Component {
  
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state ={
         MenuData:[]
    }
}

  componentDidMount(){
    window.scroll(0,0);
    this.GetVisitorDetails();
    
      axios.get(AppURL.CategoryInfo).then(response =>{
        this.setState({MenuData:response.data});
      }).catch(error=>{

      });
  }

  GetVisitorDetails = ()=>{
    axios.get(AppURL.VisitorDetails).then().catch()
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment> 
     

      <NavMenuDesktop data={this.state.MenuData}/>
          
          <HomeTop />
      <Container fluid={"true"}>
             <Categories />
             <NewArrival />
            <FeaturedProducts />
            <Collection />
            <FooterDesktop/>
           </Container>

 </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 0):

in constructor use `super(props)` then write the myView const in componentDidMount() function like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
 const CatList = this.props.data;

      const MyView = CatList.map((CatList,i)=>{
        return <div key={i.toString()}>
         <NavDropdown.Item href="">{CatList.category_name}</NavDropdown.Item>
          </div>
        });

    window.scroll(0,0);
    this.GetVisitorDetails();
    
      axios.get(AppURL.CategoryInfo).then(response =>{
        this.setState({MenuData:response.data});
      }).catch(error=>{

      });
  }
```